# How to plot multiple curve in a same plot with Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate

The manipulate function in *Mathematica* allows the users to adjust the values of the parameters in a graphical way. How do I plot multiple functions in a same graph and also I can use manipulate at the same time?

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   Plot[f1(x+n)], {x, 
     0.0001, 1}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}],
   Plot[f2(x+n)], {x, 
     0.0001, 1}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]}],
   {n, 1, 10}]
```

with give two independent plots with single curve in each. How should I do multiple curve in a **same plot?**

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
f1[x_] := x^2;
f2[x_] := x^4;
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f1[x + n], f2[x + n]}, {x, 0.0001, 1}, PlotRange->{-10, 10}],
 {n, 1, 10}]
```

The documentation for Plot shows an example of doing exactly this on the second line.
[Plot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

Comment: and how to indicate which is which?

Comment: You could try adding ,PlotLegends->LineLegend["Expressions"] after your PlotRange, but I tend to see the more you have to fiddle with your plot to make it look like you think it must the more grief you will have. And I don't even try to help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bill's answer but adding Epilog[] for labeling, try

```
f1[x_] := x^2;
f2[x_] := x^4;
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f1[x + n], f2[x + n]}, {x, 0.0001, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, Epilog -> {
    (Text[
      Style["f1", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 10, 
       Red], {.6, f1[n + .6] + .6}]),
    (Text[
      Style["f2", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 10, 
       Blue], {.6, f2[n + .6] + .6}])
    }], {n, 1, 10}]
```

[image]